# How to create new res folder in Android Studio

Tags: android-studio

I want to add localized strings for my android app. Therefore I need a values-xx folder in my Res folder.

The original values folder has a blue dot, so I tried creating a new Package, but a package can't contain a hyphen so this must be wrong. Instead I tried right-clicking res and choosing New -> Android resource directory, but this time nothing happens. No dialog or reaction of any sort as I can see.

How do I create a values-xx folder?

Edit: I can create the folder from file explorer and it all works good. It is just irritating to not be able to do it from inside Android Studio.

Edit2: This bug is fixed in newer versions of Android Studio.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This bug is fixed in newer versions of Android Studio.

Comment: Using Android 1.02 and the problem is still in.  Although the directory exists on the hdd, it's still not shown in the project explorer of AS...

Comment: It's to say, AS 1.0.2 doesn't show an extra directory, say "values-es", but will show in the "values" directory an extra "strings.xml" directory with in there, the different "strings.xml" files. Next to it (in light-gray) the location for the language (apart from English) will be shown.  Example: "strings.xml" (for the default English strings, "strings.xml (es)" for the Spanish strings and "strings.xml (nl)" for the Dutch/Belgian strings.  Weird way of showing, I was expecting different locale depending "values" directories instead...

Answer (score 29):

When you are in the Android view (rather than Project or Packages) in Android studio, you just need to right click the "values" directory and choose New > "Values resource file".

[image]

That gives you a chose of different resources you can add. For example, if you want to add a different language to your app you can choose the Language option and press the ">>" button. If you want Swahili then select that from the list, type "strings" for the file name, and press OK.

[image]

Android Studio will automatically create a `values-sw` directory with the new strings.xml file in it. And in your Android file view you conveniently see both strings files together.

[image]

And it is a similar process for adding other types of resources ([see my other example](https://stackoverflow.com/a/29454804/3681880)). You no longer have to manually add the directories (but you can do that too by right clicking the res directory and choosing New > Android resource directory).

Comment: For info, when I tried to do this in Android Studio V1.1.0, it created the folder as "values-rDE", then didn't recognise it when running. Changed the folder name to "values-de", did a clean and rebuild and it seems ok.

Comment: It is necessary to type "strings.xml" in the "File name" field in the dialog. Then the "OK" button will become enabled. Without strings.xml in the new "values-xx" directory, Android Studio will not show this empty directory in any way.

Answer (score 4):

I had the same problem, what I did was create a values-xx folder inside the main directory (main>>right click>>new>>directory) and then moved that folder to res/ directory.

It's not beautiful but it is a workaround to create a folder with Android studio.

Answer (score 1):

The values-xx folder we created is not showing, but when we create a file its asking 
=>I have created values-21 folder and then tried with creating an xml and it asks for choosing a directory
=>I have updated to Android 1.02

**Check the values-21**
[image: Sample]

Answer (score 1):

Lets assume i Want to create a folder named "Daylight" under res.

Step 1:
Right click on res.

Step 2:
Then go to New.

Step 3:
Then go to Folder.

Step 4:
Then go to Res Folder Option and select.

A window will be open.

Step 5:
At that window check the unchecked box "Change Folder Location"

and as assumed we have to create folder "Daylight"

Step 6:
SO name the newly created folder as daylight, in this format. src/main/res/Daylight

Step 7:
Then, Finally Click finish.

Comment: If you uncheck 'change folder location' you can no longer proceed in android studio 1.4

Answer (score 1):

If you have already created a new directory but just don't see it in the Project Tools window. Do this

Click on *Project Tools window >> Android(Drop Down) >> Click Project*. 
Now you'll see all your Directories in res. See the picture:

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Its very simple. I too had trouble initially.
Lets break it stepwise:-
1) Open your project
2) Right click the res folder
3) Choose New
4) Chose Directory
5) Name the directory.

Thats it!! It works for a fresh project everytime!

Answer (score 0):

For those finding this answer when trying to add a new res folder to a library.

Right-click java/kotlin folder > New > Folder > Res Folder