# Can't create a menu in android

Tags: android-studio, menu

I am in the process of trying to add a main menu to my app.

From the google docs:

> To define the menu, create an XML file inside your project's res/menu/ directory and build the menu with the following elements:

I created a "menu" file in the /res folder. However it didn't appear even though trying to create a new "menu" folder resulted in an error, meaning it exists but does not appear in "android" view.
So according to [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26811212/android-studio-newly-created-directory-not-appearing-in-folders-view) I changed to packages view to see my newly created menu directory.

I tried to create a new resource file in my menu directory. Then this happens:

[image]

I am currently stuck.

Answer (score 0):

change to android view then right click res folder -> select new android resource file. see [image: screenshot] then window will show, select "Resource Type" to MENU and input file name then it will automatically create the parent MENU folder and menu resource file. see [image: screenshot]

Comment: you get this error because menu folder filename must be "menu" not "Menu or menus etc"

Comment: I did what you did, and I still get "incorrect directory". https://imgur.com/a/l2gqu

Comment: I fixed the error myself. The folder filename was "menu" but it was "Values" type and not "menu" type. Created a new "menu" type directory and it worked! Shall I add it as an edit or answer it myself?

Comment: nicee! you can add it as an answer for easy lookup.. :)

Answer (score 0):

the menu that you haved created under res should start with capital letter. menu not Menu