# New created "values" folder is not visible in Android Studio

Tags: android, android-studio

In Android Studio, I want to create the folders `values-v14` `values-v21` inside the `res` folder.

But when I tried to make it like: right click on `res` folder select option `New >Directory`, then after creating the folder, it is not visible in Android Studio. But when I select the option `Show in Explorer`, then it is visible.

How do I create a folder in Android Studio, so that I can change files like `styles.xml`, etc?

Answer (score 107, accepted):

Try to switch from `Android` to `Project` as shown below

[image]

Answer (score 47):

Switching from the `Android` view to the `Project` view will allow you to see the directory structure, but it is less convenient for viewing and editing Android files.

There is a better way. Don't use `New > Directory`.

Right click `values` and choose `New > Values resource file`.

[image]

Select `Version` from the list and click the `>>` button. Write `styles` as the file name and `14` as the version number and click ok. (Repeat all this for version 21.)

[image]

Android Studio will automatically create `values-v14` and `values-v21` directories with the new `styles.xml` files in them. And in your Android project view you conveniently see all three `styles.xml` files together.

[image]

Other directories and resource files can be similarly added.

- [Layout files](https://stackoverflow.com/a/29454804/3681880)
- [Language translations](https://stackoverflow.com/a/29454646/3681880)

Answer (score 5):

You can also manage language stuff with the editor, it´s a little faster.

[image: String Editor Window]

Comment: @Suragch Right click the strings.xml file and then "Open Translations Editor"

Answer (score 0):

Instead to looking for the file from ANDROID, go to PROJECT and then look for the folder, you will find it there...

Answer (score 0):

I believe this is like version control, where the folder exists, but you need a file inside in order to view it. I just ran into this, and the folders existed but didn't show up until I had a file inside of them.

I hate to think this is by design. The use-case of a developer hiding their own work-space? Collapsing makes more sense

Answer (score 0):

it's so simple to find your new values-v21 or recently created..
(1) - Go to **project files**
(2) - **app** > **src** > **main** > **res**
(3) - if here is not visible your directory then
(4) - right click on **res** and select **show in explorer**
(5) - Go inside **res** here all your files are shows
(6) - Then Go inside **values** > copy **style** file from there and come back to paste inside your **values-v21** folder
(7) - you are done .. go to  your android studio and see your folder values-v21 is appearing.

Note :- Your folder was empty so you folder was not appear in android studio.