# Android Studio not showing newly created resource values automatically

Tags: android, android-studio

I have a problem that any newly created resource values, (like the new layout, new menu, new animations ) are not showing automatically in IDE. Every time I want to rebuild to take effect that values.

Actually, it is not a big problem for me, but I can't figure it out. I have done restarting, cleaning, and clear the caches too. But no luck.

And I checked the power options and it is ok.

If anyone who solved this problem please help me.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: refer https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27896889/new-created-values-folder-is-not-visible-in-android-studio

Comment: @sasikumar They solved the problem by finding it. Ok, I know the files and values are there, but it is not indexed automatically.

Answer (score 0):

I believe you have issues with some plugins/jars that support the functioning of Android Studio. Try updating it with the full package (including SDK tools), avoid patch-based updates.

Comment: yeh I forgot to mention the third party plugins. let me check

Comment: I have checked my plugins and found one, It is Android support Plugin. It crashing every time. And I checked the update option and found unlucky. There is no update option. And I tried to disable, but it shows disabling 7 more plugins and I can't apply the changes