# can we create values folder on the basis of both size and language?

Tags: android, android-layout, android-resources

I have idea on separating values folder based on the size like `ldpi, mdpi,hdpi,xhdpi,xxhdpi,xxxhdpi` and `small, large ,normal,large,xlarge` . And for separating the folders based on language we'll use `values-(language code)`. Apart from this can we separate the values folder base on both size and language? If possible how?

I want to show for **small devices** with font size of `12sp` for one language and `18sp` for another language. like values-small-te and values-small-en.

I tried with `values-small-te` but not worked :( . let me know if any way exists.

thanq in advance.

Answer (score 0):

**For language**

you can write in **String** file that is you can create different files for different languange in string directorie

like

> strings.xml(hi), strings.xml(guj), strings.xml(ta)

**For font**

you have to create different file in dimens directories to support different devices

like

> dimens.xml(hdpi), dimens.xml(ldpi), dimens.xml(mdpi),
>   dimens.xml(xdpi), dimens.xml(xxhdpi), dimens.xml(sw480dp) ,
>   dimens.xml(sw600dp) , dimens.xml(sw720dp)

Please check this [link to create directories](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17146929/how-to-create-new-res-folder-in-android-studio).

Comment: yes exactly, but my requirement is, I want to show for small devices with font size of 12sp for one language and 18sp for another language. like values-small-te and values-small-en

Comment: yes you can do that. please follow my answer you will get it.

Comment: then how to create values folder ?

Comment: ok. for that in resouce create values name directory and than in that create .xml file. in that you can create multiple .xml files to support different devices.

Comment: check http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17146929/how-to-create-new-res-folder-in-android-studio

Comment: Nope. Combining both the things is not possible I think.