# Android project res folder not showing all directory

Tags: android, gradle

I tried to add some directories to the res folder in my android project(in Android Studio).

What I get in Android Studio

[image: What I get in Android Studio]

What's my real folder structure

[image: What's my real folder structure]

I don't know that much about `gradle` but here is some code from `gradle`

```
dependencies {
    compile fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])
    androidTestCompile('com.android.support.test.espresso:espresso-core:2.2.2', {
        exclude group: 'com.android.support', module: 'support-annotations'
    })
    compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:26.+'
    compile 'com.android.support.constraint:constraint-layout:1.0.2'
    testCompile 'junit:junit:4.12'
}

allprojects {
    repositories {
        jcenter()
    }
}

task clean(type: Delete) {
    delete rootProject.buildDir
}
```

the code is not in the same folder

Comment: No errors here :). It's supposed to be like this.  If you would try to add new item let's say inside drawable folder, you would get dialog asking which drawable folder to put in.

Comment: Ohh, tried to add something and got the dialog, but I like the old fashion project style so will probably use that instead. 
But thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Below you application name, click at dropdown and select Project then you will see all directories
[image]

Comment: Thanks for the answer, but I feel kinda dumb not realising this.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem, what I did was create a values-xx folder inside the main directory  and then moved that folder to res/ directory.

> Main -> Right click -> new -> directory

It's not beautiful but it is a workaround to create a folder with Android studio.

I follow it from [How to Create New Res Folder in Android Studio](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17146929/how-to-create-new-res-folder-in-android-studio)

Above your the file directory view in Android Studio is a drop down which currently is most likely set to Android. Change it to Project and you should be able to see all your files.

Answer (score 0):

There is no mistake here. this is my **res** directory:
[image]

and take a look at my **project** directory:

[image]

but when you collapse each of them for example my **drawable** folder this is what it looks like:

[image]

you can notice that every images has **mdpi** or **hdpi** etc. indicated to know what folder it is stored. your resources are there, do not worry.

Answer (score 0):

For me, I had refactored and renamed an XML file from `main.xml` to `a_main.xml`.

My directory folder for my whole project is also called main.
So refactoring the XML also changed the name in the directory path within my module Gradle to `a_main`, but did not change the name of my directory. In the module Gradle, I found the `srcDirs` and changed it from `a_main` back to `main`. The project lives on.

[image: project]

Comment: This should be an answer which solves the problem but instead reads like another problem desription. Please [edit] and rephrase to make the answering part more obvious. If it actually is a problem instead of an answer please delete and ask a separate new question instead https://stackoverflow.com/questions/ask